# How does neo4j perform in time and space complexity for given type of nodes, relationships and queries?

Tags: performance, storage, neo4j, time-complexity, graph-databases

Consider I'm going to have following things in my graph:

```
100 Million nodes, More than 1 Billion connections/relationships

Node properties: around 10 properties, mix of int, doubles, strings, HashMaps etc.

Relationship properties: around 10 double values and 2-3 string (with avg 50 chars) values
```

Now, Suppose I want to update all node and relationship property values, by querying neighbors on each node once. i.e. say as,

```
step1: search a node, say X, with given Id,
step2: get it's neighbours,
step3: update node properties of X and all relationship properties between X and it's neighbors.
```

Repeat these 3 steps for all nodes once.
How much time will it take for once update of all nodes(approx time is OK for me, may be in seconds / minutes / hrs) given following system configuration:

```
Two dual core processors, 3.0 GHz each, 4*4 GB memory, 250 GB Hard disk space.
```

How much approximate storage space will be required for above mentioned data?

Please help me by providing any approximate, sample performance (time and storage) analysis.
Any sample performance analysis will help me to visualize my requirements. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Size consideration is pretty easy for node/relationships. Each node is 9 Bytes, and each relationship is 33 Bytes.

```
9B x 100M = 900 Million Bytes =~ 858.3 Megabytes for nodes
33B x 1B = 33 Billion bytes =~ 30.7 Gigabytes for relationships
```

As for the computation, it's tough to gauge that. Neo4j cache isn't 1-to-1 with what is on disk, so your storage may be ~31Gb, but you'll need much more then that to store it in cache. The way neo4j stores the information on disk is efficient for this type of traversal though, as they store all relationships and properties for a node in a linked list, so accessing them through an iterator is more effient then searching for one type of relationship.

It would be hard to give you an estimate, but I'd say since you are going through duplicate relationships, what can fit on RAM vs Disk, etc. My guess would be a few hours(<6Hrs.) given your system and  size requirements.

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas . One question on your answer.. Whatever size you mentioned, does it include indexing too? If not, how much memory will indexing (nodes) take? And, will it be only indexing from where query on node will be served? And so, will only indexing get loaded into cache?

I have following system:
3.5 GB dual core processor machine from cloud (m1.medium), with around 400GB hard drive space.. and cache of approx 4GB..

And the last one, I didn't understand about duplicate relationships..

Comment: Considering this system configuration, how much will be estimated time for updating all relationships and nodes once?

Comment: I do not believe cache is indexed, but it's fast despite that fact. Not entirely sure about index size, but it's usually nominal, it stores it pretty compact. Again, it's tough to estimate, but several hours is the best i can give you. You could always load it up and test.

Comment: i dont think that hw would run such a huge db in few hours. my guess is several days at its best. maybe running the server in distributed mode across several servers could help.