# neo4j requires more space than expected

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a neo4j server including 10 million nodes.

I'm trying to create 1 billion relationships, by adding each node 100 relationships.

I wrote a java embedded program and it updates the relationships.

So far, the execution time looks not bad: approximately 15 million relationships per hour. (using 3GB heap size);
But, the disk usage is increasing far more than expected : appr. 6 GB per hour .(15 m relationships..)

For my understanding, relationship takes 33B. So, when adding 15 million relationships (with no properties at all except for the name), it should take about 0.5 GB . instead it takes 10 times more!

Why relationships take so much disk usage?

Comment: Are you using the bulk inserter or the normal transactional method for your creation? When you say it's taking up all that space, is it just the `relationshipstore` or is it the entire neo4j directory?

Comment: below post might help:::

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074593/how-does-neo4j-perform-in-time-and-space-complexity-for-given-type-of-nodes-rel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to clean up your logical log (to be sure, check which files are growing fast). You can configure this via a configuration parameter: `keep_logical_logs=false`

Comment: Hi Wes. You're right, the logical files took increased up to 40 GB. I stopped the service, cleaned the files, changed in `neo4j.properties` file to `keep_logical_logs="2G size"`. But, when started it again, got the same problem, it got much over 2G... How can I change configuration?

Comment: It should keep "more than 2G", depending on your transactions and the files they're in... for heavy insert load I would just do `false`.

Answer (score 0):

See Code:

```
int number = (int) parseLongWithUnit( numberWithUnit );
```

More than "2G size" can not set by bytes,but you can set XXX files/XXX hours/XXX days/XXX txs

keep_logical_logs for backup/HA sync etc.